# Subaru Impreza rear wiper relay?

Tags: electrical, subaru, part-identification, relay

I have a faulty rear wiper relay on an impreza,  but I cannot identify it's part number.

It's 12v, but what Amperage?

It has a part number and details as follows

- 12V5B-1T
- 642N
- NILES JAPAN

It has 5 pins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean you're unsure whether the part number is 12V5B-1T or 642N? Odds are good it is one of those. Try searching for each (e.g., feed "12V5B-1T relay" to the Google) and see what you get. It is very likely you'll get specs with a picture.

By the way, it is probably not a 5-pole (five switched circuits) but rather 5-pin or five connectors or some such. A relay will usually have 2 connections for the coil (to operate the relay), at least one common connection for the load, and then one connection for each pole. So a 5-pole relay would have at least seven connections, and more likely eight (or more).

Comment: 5 pin,  yes... Sorry.  I find the parts all over the Web,  but never the power rating

Comment: Maybe add specs to the search? I just did a quick search and found one on Amazon that is rated at 40 A. Relay ratings will have a voltage rating for the coil, and may have two different ratings for the contacts, one for AC and another for DC. The AC rating will usually be higher, either voltage or current or both. That's because with AC arcing is reduced or eliminated at each zero crossing. You may also find horsepower ratings.

Comment: Is there any risk putting in a 40A rated device,  when the original is (for example ) 25A?

Comment: No, as long as it fits. A higher rating means the contacts are bigger or better built. I'd expect that selecting by the part number would get you the same rating though…

Comment: Thanks.  Then my only criteria will be to find a part with the same pin labout

Comment: Actually you want more than just the same pin layout, you also want the same connections through the pins, again matching the part number should be ensuring that that is the same. I guess with the amp rating a vendor could have a way to build a "better than original" relay and thus use the original number but also rate it for a higher load.

Comment: More than welcome!